# Some guidance tips as a brand new user to Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, new-users

I'm a brand new user to Stack Exchange and I was wondering if I could get some guidance on how this site works and how to ask questions. I have been told by my friends I need to be clear and understandable when writing, otherwise I will get downvoted and put in "the slaughterhouse".

When I first signed up, there was a page that explained how to write good questions. However, it seemed quite vague and I'm not sure it was massively helpful. Can I have some guidance from you guys with more experience in the Stack Exchange community on the basics of how Stack Exchange works, as well as an explanation of how to write good questions on Stack Exchange?

It would be very much appreciated!

Comment: The first thing you need to realize is that being downvoted is in no way equivalent to being "put in the slaughter house". It's just a reflection that some members of the community found your post to be unclear, not useful, and/or evidencing insufficient research effort. It's a good signal that you should consider whether a revision (edit) is in order. If not, it's at least a signal that your point of view is unpopular, which isn't nearly as bad as getting slaughtered. Votes are a content rating system; nothing more, nothing less. They don't represent you as a person. This isn't a video game.

Comment: My friends have said they have been auto banned for being downvoted so often. That makes it mean something correct?

P.S I think I accidentally clicked on the red flag and reported this comment, any Mod who read this, ignore, it sorry for that.

Comment: There is an automated post ban, yes; it is activated when the system detects that a poster has a track record of low quality content, and prevents them from posting more until they learn from their mistakes.  There isn't really any personalized advice we can give you; it all has to be general so it's applicable to the widest audience.

Comment: @fbueckert so the problem needs to be general or else it will be counted as a bad question and will hurt your reputation?

Comment: We'd prefer questions be able to help far more than just the asker; that's the premise SE was built on, after all.  That doesn't automatically mean that your problem is a bad one if you can't see it helping others; it does mean you'll need to put in effort to follow the guidance already provided.  Which is necessary no matter how useful you expect the question to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some links of Stack Exchange in the help center, and other ones.

Okay, let's start with tour which you already read:

*https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour*

And the whole help center page:

*https://meta.stackexchange.com/help*

There are some good links there, e.g.

*https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic*

*https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask*

*https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask*

---

*https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct*

*https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta*

---

*https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer*

And some other ones.

You can keep learning these and there are some more about how the site works. They are all good.

Comment: Thank you and I will use this information to the best of my abilities however it feels like that's all generic stuff that is partially/mostly obvious. My friends say answers half to be perfect or you risk getting chewed up and swallowed. I this true? And what can you tell me from personal experience that might help?

Comment: @Pured1974 That is correct! also learning from this, if a answer is helpful, you should up-vote it, and if it answers your question, you should accept it, https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: OK, as a final question, can you give me any personal experience on how to write a good question?

Comment: @Pured1974 - Read Jon Skeet's two blog posts on how to [ask a question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [answer a question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/). They're geared towards Stack Overflow but there's good information in there regardless of where you plan to post on the SE network.